# XMLHttpRequest does not render template - Flask, Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a web app where in the home page, there are two ways to upload an audio file.

1) File upload.

2) Record on-site and submit.

This initial home page can be seen here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8z83es4r/)

So, we POST the data to `/sheet` which is seen here (this is a Flask server).

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html', request="GET")

@app.route('/sheet', methods=['POST'])
def sheet():
  file = request.files['file']
  if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    pitches = handle_file(file)
  else:
    flash('Wrong file extension.')
    return redirect(request.url)
  print "this happens!"
  return render_template('sheet.html', pitches=pitches)
```

So, the issue is that when this is done using the file upload method, this works. The `sheet.html` gets rendered and the results (`pitches`, from `handle_file()`) are seen.

**However**, when this is done using **recording & submitting**, even though I get `pitches` (the results), "this happens!" gets printed but the `sheet.html` is **NOT** rendered. The screen remains at `index.html`. Why is that?

Comment: Could you show your recording and submitting code? What is happening in recording and submitting and how is it connected to the `sheet` function?

Comment: Both methods (file upload, recording & submitting) are shown in the JSFiddle. Both methods eventually call `sheet`, however.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you need to split the file submission and showing the result. Define you `sheet` route this way:

```
from flask import (Flask, render_template, request,
                   redirect, flash, session, url_for)

...

@app.route('/sheet', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sheet():
    file = request.files['file']
    # if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    if file:
        #   pitches = handle_file(file)
        pitches = ['pitch_0', 'pitch_1', 'pitch_2']
    else:
        flash('Wrong file extension.')
        return redirect(request.url)
    print("THIS HAPPENS!")
    session['pitches'] = pitches
    return redirect(url_for('result'))
```

Define new route `result`:

```
@app.route('/result')
def result():
    pitches = session['pitches']
    return render_template('result.html', pitches=pitches)
```

This is the result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Results page</h1>
<p>This is the results page.</p>
    {{ pitches }}
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how your `submit` function should look like:

```
function submit() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', audioFile, 'audio.wav');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('POST', '/sheet', true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        window.location.href = '/result';
      }
  }
  xhr.send(fd);
}
```

In your case XMLHttpRequest executs correctly and it receives the html response but id does not render it in browser. I might be wrong, but I think the way XMLHttpRequest request works is to receive data, for instance, some json and process it further or if you need to get on a new page you need to redirect user after the response is returned yourself. 
In any case my answer solves your problem.